# Possible to get cv2.line pixel coords without having to draw (looking for speed increase)?

Tags: python, opencv

```
def func_get_line_coords(blank_canvas, coord_pairs_to_draw):

    to_return = list()
    for idx, coord_pair in enumerate(coord_pairs_to_draw):
        cv2.line(blank_canvas, coord_pair[0], coord_pair[1], idx+1, 1)
        to_return.append(np.argwhere(blank_canvas==idx+1))
    return to_return

blank_canvas = np.zeros((1000,1000), dtype=np.uint8)
coord_pairs_to_draw = [[(23, 76), (900, 4)], [(890, 640), (32, 500)], [(876, 43), (29, 900)], [(1, 3), (709, 82)], [(47, 23), (900, 900)]]
pixel_coords = func_get_line_coords(blank_canvas, coord_pairs_to_draw)
```

As per the title, I am trying to get a list of coords for a line produced between 2 coordinates with cv2. I am not interested in the plot itself, and **it seems that having to actually draw the line, then find matching coords may be a unnecessary overhead**. Above is the fastest implementation I can come up with (this is a toy example) using this type of approach.

I am trying to stick with results 'as opencv would produce' to avoid inconsistencies with values should I later plot with opencv itself (I'm not sure whether exact pixel position may vary between different algorithms to the one opencv uses).

**EDIT** : I've edited the question slightly to convey that I have an approach (by drawing and extracting), but I am looking to speed this up and thought eliminating the draw then read may be a way to do this.

Comment: How would the result be if cv2 drew the line and you extracted it from the image? Shape, array....

Comment: @Mace That's what I'm doing in the code example above (if I understand you correctly). I am trying to make it run faster (in a real situation with a lot more lines to process). I thought drawing and then extracting was an inefficient way of doing it, but maybe its my implementation that is inefficient...

Comment: what if you just drew the line of a specific color, and used np.where to find the points of this color? it's hacky but you'd just have 1/16,581,375 chances (1/255*255*255) to mistakenly sample an unrelated point

Comment: @Nicolas Gervais That's what I'm doing in the code example above (if I understand you correctly). I am trying to make it run faster (in a real situation with a lot more lines to process). I thought drawing and then extracting was an inefficient way of doing it, but maybe its my implementation that is inefficient...

Comment: AFAIK, this is the simplest way https://stackoverflow.com/a/61439375/2836621

Comment: oh you're right i'm sorry. seems like both commenters have said exactly what you already said. sorry to waste your time!

Comment: @Mark Setchell Thanks. With `rr,cc =  skimage.draw.line(r0,c0,r1,c1) coords = np.column_stack(cc,rr)` I get a reduction in runtime of ~75%. Results look sufficient.