# Python : find pixel in specific diagonal

Tags: python, numpy

actually i retrieve the coords of black pixels in all my picture like that:

```
frame = np.array(img)
frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
xcoords, ycoords = np.where((frame[:, :, 0:3] == [0, 0, 0]).all(2))
```

But i want to retrieve all black pixels in some specific area of my picture. But this area is some lines like that :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOZZP.png

Can you help me please ?

Comment: 'I want to retrieve all black pixels in some specific area of my picture' - could you clarify, please?

Comment: What do the red lines in your image mean?

Comment: This is the area where i want to search black pixels, or we can say if we have a black screen the red lines are the answer that i want.
I want an array with location of all black pixels, like i already did, but it actually return all black pixels of the entire screen. I want all black pixel who are only in these red lines

Comment: I want to search black pixels in the shape of these red lines

Comment: So did you draw the lines? I mean do you have the start and end `[x,y]` coordinates of the lines?

Comment: I draw the lines
And yes, i know where i have to find, this is a line:
    frame = cv2.line(frame, (960, 540), (340, 162), (0, 0, 255), 1)

Comment: If you look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61439375/2836621 you can see how to get the row (rr) and column (cc) of all pixels along a line so you should be able to adapt that to get the coordinates of all the points on your lines.

Comment: Okay thanks ! Now i have two array with coordinates of all points on my lines.
I tried this to retrieve all the black pixels in these coordinates but it doesn't works. I don't know how am i supposed to deal with that ?
`rr, cc = line(540, 960, 20, 200)`
`xcoords, ycoords = np.where((frame[rr, cc, 0:3] == [0, 0, 0]).all(2))`